# Reading an Excel file fails due to "embedded null characters"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I open the excel file, the error "File Format and Extension Don’t Match" appears, probably related this this.

I've tried reading it with pandas but I get the error "embedded null character"

```
file_path = r"C:\Users\my_username\Documents\my_file.xls" 

file1 = open(file_path)
 
df = pd.read_csv(file1.read())
```

Also tried,

```
file_path = "C:/Users/my_username\Documents/my_file.xls" 

file1 = open(file_path)

df = pd.read_csv(file1.read())
```

I tried the same code as above using read_excel, instead of read_csv, both resulting in "embedded null character"

Comment: Try: `df = pd.read_excel("C:\Users\my_username\Documents\my_file.xls")`. I don't understand why you need the `open` method here. you can read directly the excel using `read_excel` method.

Comment: Thank you. That removes the "embedded bull character" issue! Getting a "file format cannot be determined".

Answer (score 0):

Try to read directly the excel file:

```
 file_path = r"C:\Users\my_username\Documents\my_file.xls" 
 df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
```

Comment: Use forward slashes in the path literal or escape them (or use a raw string).